# Pairing the Pi over BT 4.0 LE to a MS Universal Foldable Keyboard fails

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard

## Background

I'm trying to pair my RasPi with the new Microsoft Universal Foldable Keyboard, which requires BT 4.0 LE HCI connectivity from the host. On my Pi it is provided by CSR based Bluetooth 4.0 dongle. **Scanning works, but pairing and connecting don't. What goes wrong?**

## How things stand currently

I'm running Raspbian on a Pi 2, with the latest raspberrypi-bootloader/kernel allowed by my Adafruit PiTFT (1.20150904-1) and BlueZ 5.34 stack.

`hcitool lescan` recognizes the keyboard when it's set in pairing mode.

```
C4:E0:1E:08:DC:D3 UniversalFoldableKb
C4:E0:1E:08:DC:D3 (unknown)
```

but when I try the pairing command `bluez-simple-agent hci0 C4:E0:1E:08:DC:D3`, while having plain `bluez-simple-agent` running in another session on the Pi, it merely states:

```
Creating device failed: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed: Page Timeout
```

At the same time `hcidump` gives:

```
2015-09-19 02:02:31.779409 > HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4 Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) status 0x00 ncmd 1
2015-09-19 02:02:36.902080 > HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11
status 0x04 handle 0 bdaddr C4:E0:1E:08:DC:D3 type ACL encrypt 0x00
Error: Page Timeout
```

My understanding is the `bluez-simple-agent` doesn't know that it's supposed to use the HID-over-GATT (LE HID) profile. There might be other factors too, see *Other experiments* below for secondary indications.

There was a curious message while checking `dmesg`

```
Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
```

which might indicate a separate problem with BT devices after updating `raspberrypi-bootloader` and kernel from 3.18 to whatever's in the 1.20150904-1 package. I don't know if these things are related.

## Other experiments

After a precautionary `hcitool hci0 down; hcitool hci0 up`, `hcitool leinfo` states `Could not create connection: Connection timed out`. `hcidump` shows:

```
2015-09-19 02:14:03.593773 > HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) status 0x00 ncmd 1
```

And apparently something hangs, because now I *have* to cycle the interface to have anything work again. Same with `hcitool lecc`, the connection just times out without any extra information and the interface must be cycled to recover it.

## Notes

Please let me know if I've overlooked some log or some other such resource - I will then update my question with the relevant bits.

Answer (score 2):

The message you have seen in `dmesg`:

```
Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
```

this is a known kernel issue and this is fixed in the Raspberry Pi Kernel with this commit:
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commit/d8949aad3eab5d396f4fefcd581773bf07b9a79e

In the current noobs install you have kernel 4.1.19 that does not yet contain the fix, but you can perform a kernel upgrade running

```
rpi-update
```

You will get a update to a kernel that contains the fix (in my case it was 4.4.7).

This should remove the `dmesg` error message.

To get the keyboard running I uninstalled gui-bluetooth modules and restarted the PI to work only with `bluetoothctl`.

```
bluetoothctl 
[bluetooth]# agent KeyboardDisplay   
[bluetooth]# default-agent   
[bluetooth]# scan on   
[bluetooth]# scan off   
[bluetooth]# pair <device>
```

This time `bluetoothctl` should show you the password that you needed to type in on the keyboard (+ return).
After pairing your can connect and trust the device as usual and you should be able to type on the MS Foldable Keyboard.

Comment: I am running in exactly the same issue, but I already have `!conn->smp` check right before `l2cap_chan_lock`. Function `smp_ready_cb` (which sets `conn->smp`) is still called ~100-200 us too late and therefore `smp_conn_security` prints error `"SMP security requested but not available"`. Is there any way to delay a bit?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers didn't work for me, so after going on a wild goose chase and compiling bluez from source (which didn't work) I reverted back to **bluez 5.23-2+rpi2**, and I remembered reading that adding the `--experimental` parameter to bluez enables Bluetooth LE support.
So I edited `/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service` and added `--experimental` to the end of the `ExecStart` line, rebooted the Pi, and found that I could then pair using `bluetoothctl`.

I have since switched to Raspbian testing (stretch) and found that I needed to downgrade bluez to the same version in order for my keyboard to keep working.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problems using the rpi 3 and found the following:

I tried to use blueman to set up the keyboard but while it found the device and attempted to connect, it failed.

Instead I used bluetoothctl from the cm:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller B8:27:EB:98:79:A3 raspberrypi [default]
[NEW] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C Universal Mobile Keyboard

[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:98:79:A3 Discovering: yes
[CHG] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C RSSI: -59
[CHG] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C RSSI: -82
[CHG] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C RSSI: -55
```

Once i confirmed the address of the keyboard I tried to connect to it:

```
[bluetooth]# connect 28:18:78:F9:03:5C
Attempting to connect to 28:18:78:F9:03:5C
[CHG] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C Modalias: usb:v045Ep0802d0092
[CHG] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C UUIDs:
    00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C Connected: no
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

But this failed too!

I then tried to pair the device:

```
[bluetooth]# pair 28:18:78:F9:03:5C
Attempting to pair with 28:18:78:F9:03:5C
[CHG] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C Connected: yes
[agent] Passkey: 038594
[agent] Passkey: 038594
[agent] Passkey: 038594
[agent] Passkey: 038594
[agent] Passkey: 038594
[agent] Passkey: 038594
[agent] Passkey: 038594
[CHG] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C Connected: no
```

I then tried to connect again and this time it worked :-)

```
[bluetooth]# connect 28:18:78:F9:03:5C
Attempting to connect to 28:18:78:F9:03:5C
[CHG] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C Connected: yes
Connection successful
```

Finally I set the device to be trusted:

```
[bluetooth]# trust 28:18:78:F9:03:5C
[CHG] Device 28:18:78:F9:03:5C Trusted: yes
Changing 28:18:78:F9:03:5C trust succeeded
```

It must be working OK as I'm using the BT keyboard to type this!